# How to bind dataset to drop down list / combobox with display and value member

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

This is all about convert dataset to list 
where dataset including two columns like

1. ID
2. Name

all i want to convert this to an array list  and  than bind to a drop down
where Value member of  DDl  is : 'ID' 
and display member of  DDL is : name

any suggestion in this matter will be helpful to me ,

or any different idea ? 
so i can achieve  Value member and  display member easily.

Comment: What type of application? WPF, Winforms, Asp.net?

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends on your application type and your data provider type, but here is a sample:

```
// fill your data table via data adapter or whatever...
yourComboBox.DataSource = yourDataTable;
yourComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
yourComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Update:

Based on your comment, maybe this is what you mean?

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

foreach(var row in DataSet.Table['tableName'].Rows)
{
    dict.Add(row["ID"], row["Name"]);
}

yourComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
yourComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
yourComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Comment: thank you Jason Down
i already try this but main problem is convert dataset to list 
and get respected column i only want to display NAME  
but ID is value member it is for further deal

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but if all you want to do is create a list (or better yet a dictionary since you want a key-value pair) then you will want to first run code like in Tom Studee's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756705/how-to-bind-dataset-to-drop-down-list-combobox-with-display-and-value-member/6756738#6756738 Then bind the dictionary in the same manner. I'll provide an update. Still not sure if this is what you are asking, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

foreach(DataRow row in DataSet.Table['tableName'].Rows)
{
    dict.Add(row["ID"], row["Name"]);
}
```

Something along those lines should work for you. Don't have access to Visual Studio so I apologize for any basic syntax errors. This should get you a start though.

Comment: I borrowed part of your answer (slightly modified) after he added some more details. +1